# Reset variable when variable is 0

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown that goes from `100` to `0`. When it reaches `0`, I want it to be restarted. How can I do this?

```
if(sec = 0) {
    sec=100
}
else() {

}
```

Comment: `=` is used for assigning, if you want to compare use `==`

Comment: `sec = 0` should be `sec === 0`

Comment: A concise way to write it would be `sec = --sec || 100`

Comment: It could be better if you give us more info about your countdown function.

Comment: blex comment worked exelent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(sec == 0) { sec=100; }
else { sec--; }
```